# How to tell which application UFW is blocking

Tags: security, firewall, ufw

I have a Debian system running [ufw](https://wiki.debian.org/Uncomplicated%20Firewall%20%28ufw%29). I have "default deny" on all outgoing connections and I open specific communications (ports and/or IP addresses) as needed.

I use the `dmesg` log to see if anything is trying to make an outbound connection. I can usually research the IP addresses and/or ports and figure out what's going on. But, is there a way to see which **application** is is attempting to send outbound packets?

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to check `ufw` logs.

```
sudo less /var/log/ufw*
```

If there is not logs about blocking, check logging level. Remember that higher levels of logging can fill your disk fast.

FILE: /etc/ufw/ufw.conf

```
# Please use the 'ufw' command to set the loglevel. Eg: 'ufw logging medium'.
# See 'man ufw' for details.
LOGLEVEL=low
```

`man ufw` show some info about logging

```
       logging on|off|LEVEL
              toggle logging. Logged packets use the LOG_KERN syslog facility. Systems configured for rsyslog support may
              also log to /var/log/ufw.log. Specifying a LEVEL turns logging on for the specified LEVEL. The default  log
              level is 'low'.  See LOGGING for details.
........
LOGGING
       ufw  supports multiple logging levels. ufw defaults to a loglevel of 'low' when a loglevel is not specified. Users
       may specify a loglevel with:

         ufw logging LEVEL

       LEVEL may be 'off', 'low', 'medium', 'high' and 'full'. Log levels are defined as:

       off    disables ufw managed logging

       low    logs all blocked packets not matching the defined policy (with rate limiting), as well as packets  matching
              logged rules

       medium log  level  low, plus all allowed packets not matching the defined policy, all INVALID packets, and all new
              connections.  All logging is done with rate limiting.

       high   log level medium (without rate limiting), plus all packets with rate limiting

       full   log level high without rate limiting

       Loglevels above medium generate a lot of logging output, and may quickly fill up your disk.  Loglevel  medium  may
       generate a lot of logging output on a busy system.

       Specifying 'on' simply enables logging at log level 'low' if logging is currently not enabled.
```

Example of log:

```
May 22 00:06:44 HOSTNAME kernel: [12387117.150851] [UFW -->BLOCK<--] IN=<NIC> OUT= MAC=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=XXXXXXXXX LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

---

Now I see you want to know which application is sending them... Maybe application logs (failed attempts) etc..

You can also open ports, and use `nethogs` to see who is using bandwidth and go from there. Close the ports afterwards.